# Do pending transactions count towards credit utilization?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score

Usually when I use my US credit card for transactions, they are posted as pending. At this time the balance does not reflect this transaction, but available credit is reduced.

I have set a target for utilization and trying to stay within it. Since I have a small credit, I have went over my target with my pending transactions alone (i.e. balance was still $0).

I want to know, if the banks take into account pending transactions when they report credit utilization. If so should I pay ahead when the transactions are still pending?

Comment: No, pending transactions count against your available credit but since they have not posted to your balance yet, it won't affect utilization. Plus, it usually take a month end statement closing cycle before a balance is reported, so what actually is reported to be used in your utilization can change wildly during the period between reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit utilization, when you're talking about your credit report/credit score, is based on what is reported to it by the credit card companies.  This means several things.

First, most companies only report your balance periodically.  Monthly is most common, though other frequencies can apply; you would have to talk to your card issuer to find out exactly what they do.

Most often, they report your [statement balance](http://www.mycreditunion.gov/Pages/pocket-cents-understanding-credit-card-statement.aspx), which is the amount that was finalized on your card as of the statement date.  That amount wouldn't typically contain 'pending' charges, though the issuer usually allows some time for pending charges to be finalized before issuing the statement.

Since they often report the statement balance, if that's the case with your issuer, you may need to pay your balance more than once a month to keep utilization low.  They may also report on the first of the month rather than the statement balance, in which case you'd want to contact the issuer to find out exactly when they report.  You can usually identify the statement balance, if that's what they report, by checking your credit report periodically and comparing the reported balance to your past statements.